# Why does `pmset -g thermlog` behave so strangely when piped?

Tags: performance, pmset

I'm trying to create some monitoring for the thermal throttling during some build operations. For that I'd wanted to make use of `pmset -g thermlog`, which works great when used directly in the console, but seems to behave weirdly when piped to `tee` for example.

What I can observe is that these 3 lines are printed immediately, but the actual values are only emitted if another update is emitted, and for that update only the timestamp is printed immediately and the data only when another event is emitted. (For illustration purposes I only included the first "partial" event).

```
$ pmset -g thermlog | tee foo.txt
Note: No thermal warning level has been recorded
Note: No performance warning level has been recorded
2022-06-02 14:52:03 +0200
```

This doesn't happen when used without the piping.

```
$pmset -g thermlog
Note: No thermal warning level has been recorded
Note: No performance warning level has been recorded
2022-06-02 14:51:34 +0200 CPU Power notify
    CPU_Scheduler_Limit     = 100
    CPU_Available_CPUs  = 16
    CPU_Speed_Limit     = 100
```

And it works fine if I use `therm` instead of `thermlog`, altough that only ever prints the one event obviously.

```
$ pmset -g therm | tee foo.txt
Note: No thermal warning level has been recorded
Note: No performance warning level has been recorded
2022-06-02 14:51:55 +0200 CPU Power notify
    CPU_Scheduler_Limit     = 100
    CPU_Available_CPUs  = 16
    CPU_Speed_Limit     = 100
```

I actually want to consume the process output via Java's `java.lang.Process`, but there I see the same issue with the event data not being written immediately to the out stream.

Can somebody explain what is wrong here and ideally provide a fix for using `thermlog`. I know that I could just query `therm` repeatedly, but that has a lower resolution and is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `pmset -g thermlog` doesn't quit after printing, it continues monitoring for temperature changes. Could that be related somehow? (Sorry if I'm stating the obvious!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is related, and I want exactly that continued logging behavior, only that it should log all data immediately.

Comment: The usual command to monitor an ongoing log is `tail -f` so a guess at `pmset -g therm | tail -f | tee foo.txt`

Comment: @mmmmmm have you actually tried your suggestion? `pmset -g thermlog | tail -f | tee foo.txt` doesn't print anything.